# ajax live search last character

Tags: javascript, ajax, search, live

I am experimenting with the AJAX Live Search found at:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp

It transfers the value of the input via AJAX to compare it in a php-file.

This does work, but there is one thing that bothers me:

When typing in some characters and deleting all of my input (**quite quickly**), sometimes there are **still results shown, belonging to the findings of the last character I deleted**.

So typing `asdfgh` results in `no suggestion`.
But deleting all characters there is still the result for `a` showing, that is:

```
HTML a tag
HTML br tag
CSS background Property
JavaScript Date Object
JavaScript Array Object
```

I tried working around this by altering the `onkeyup` part of the code, pushing it into the javascript itself, trying different types of events, but nothing seems to fix this behaviour.

Also tested this on my mobile phone and another PC, it's all the same.

Any suggestions on what to change to get rid of this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to put a time delay in the *showResult* function.

Set a timeout to say, perhaps 50ms, and each time the *showResult* function is called, you reset it.

The timeout will do the AJAX call (what *showResult* was supposed to do).

Comment: I tried it, about 2000ms+ seem to catch up somewhat, but it does not seem to make that much of a difference... plus - waiting over 2 seconds for a live search would be much too long.

Comment: I just tried with 50ms and it looks ok. You are just deleting the word quickly   right ? I cannot reproduce the problem.